# Scroll to the very bottom of the page Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll

Having issue with scrolling method. Here is my code, by looks like it works fine, but completely ignoring self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") line.

Is there any other method by chance?

Keep in mind, I cannot use any particular element like 'self.driver.find_element_by_id' at the end, because they keep changing all the time.

```
def ViewEventHistory(self):
    self.login()
    self.controlMenu('2')
    time.sleep(2)
    view_event = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.eightdevelopment.eas.android:id/btn_event_history')
    view_event.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the problem here is that your are trying to scroll the window, but actually you need to scroll the pop-up that is opened by `view_event.click()`.

You can use a snippet I wrote for one of my projects. It accepts an optional Selenium element and scrolls it. If it's not provided, the function scrolls the main window.

```
def _scroll(self, scroll_obj=None):
    if scroll_obj:
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;', scroll_obj)
    else:
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;')
```